# Does the STL generate valgrind errors for a std::vector of std::vector if my program is fine?

Tags: c++, stl, valgrind

I use a vector of vectors in my program:

```
vector<vector<int>> vec;
```

The constructor does:

```
vec.reserve(firstDimension);
```

Now I checked my program with valgrind. Valgrind complains about a lot of:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

It seems that they are related to `vector::reserve`. This functions seems to allocate uninitialized heap memory, which makes sense. Actually, they disapear when I replace the `vec.reserve(firstDimension)` with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < firstDim; i ++){
  vec.emplace(); // just constructs a sub-vector for the second dimension
}
```

Nevertheless, I'm a bit confused now: I would expect that the STL would not generate such errors. So I wonder whether there ARE actually situations where the STL generates valgrind errors or whether this indicates a problem in my program?

Comment: Please show a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `std::vector::reserve(n)` allocates the memory required to hold at least `n` elements, but it does not construct the actual elements. 
As such, the allocated memory is just garbage, and you need to `emplace`/`insert` items onto the vector to actually construct the inner vectors.

If you know the `firstDim` and you want to default-construct the inner vectors, use `std::vecotor`'s sized constructor:

```
vector<vector<int>> vec(firstDim);
```

or use `std::vector::resize` (which actually constructs the inner vectors you need):

```
vector<vector<int>> vec;
vec.resize(firstDim);
```

Note that the first method is the preferred way of doing that.